# put all separate paragraphs of a file into a separate line

Tags: perl, sed, text-manipulation

I have a file that contains sequence data, where each new paragraph (separated by two blank lines) contain a new sequence:

```
#example

ASDHJDJJDMFFMF
AKAKJSJSJSL---
SMSM-....SKSKK
....SK


SKJHDDSNLDJSCC
AK..SJSJSL--HG
AHSM---..SKSKK
-.-GHH
```

and I want to end up with a file looking like:

```
ASDHJDJJDMFFMFAKAKJSJSJSL---SMSM-....SKSKK....SK
SKJHDDSNLDJSCCAK..SJSJSL--HGAHSM---..SKSKK-.-GHH
```

each sequence is the same length (if that helps).

I would also be looking to do this over multiple files stored in different directiories.

I have just tried

```
sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/regex/!d' ./text.txt
```

however this just deleted the entire file :S

any help would bre appreciated - doesn't have to be in sed, if you know how to do it in perl or something else then that's also great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '
    /^[[:space:]]*$/ {if (line) print line; line=""; next}
    {line=line $0}
    END {if (line) print line}
'
```

```
perl -00 -pe 's/\n//g; $_.="\n"'
```

For multiple files:

```
# adjust your glob pattern to suit, 
# don't be shy to ask for assistance
for file in */*.txt; do
    newfile="/some/directory/$(basename "$file")"
    perl -00 -pe 's/\n//g; $_.="\n"' "$file" > "$newfile"
done
```

Comment: glenn, how do i do this for multiple files in multiple directories? and then output all files into one single directory...

Comment: thanks glenn, and i was about to run the function, but I think on second thoughts it is easier to just alter the existing files. currently the one liner you have provided displays the changes in the terminal. I know that using the sed -i flag i can make the changes to the existing file. is there an equivalent for perl?

Comment: ok, it;s exactly the same. no worries. Glenn you've been a great help!

Answer (score 3):

All you're asking to do is convert a file of blank-lines-separated records (RS) where each field is separated by newlines into a file of newline-separated records where each field is separated by nothing (OFS). Just set the appropriate awk variables and recompile the record:

```
$ awk '{$1=$1}1' RS= OFS= file
ASDHJDJJDMFFMFAKAKJSJSJSL---SMSM-....SKSKK....SK
SKJHDDSNLDJSCCAK..SJSJSL--HGAHSM---..SKSKK-.-GHH
```

Answer (score 1):

A Perl one-liner, if you prefer:

```
perl -nle 'BEGIN{$/=""};s/\n//g;print $_' file
```

The `$/` variable is the equivalent of `awk`'s `RS` variable.  When set to the empty sting (`""`) it causes two or more empty lines to be treated as one empty line.  This is the so-called "paragraph-mode" of reading.  For each record read, all newline characters are removed. The `-l` switch adds a newline to the end of each output string, thus giving the desired result.

Comment: `perl -pE'BEGIN{$/="";$\="\n"} s/\n//g;'` is an alternative. The `-p` option prints `"$_$\"` after each iteration.

Comment: The assignment `$/ = ""` can be done with the command-line option `-00`, giving `perl -n00lpe "s/\n//g" file`

Comment: @Borodin: is the `-n` option a mistype?

Comment: @sid_com: Yes. Thank you. Should be `perl -00lpe "s/\n//g" file`

Answer (score 0):

just try to find those double linebreaks: \n or \r and replace first those with an special sign like :$:
after that you replace every linebreak with an empty string to get the whole file in one line.
next, replace your special sign with a simple line break :)